# how to access property like dict.get('key') in python Class

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Investor:
    def __init__(self, profile):
        self.profile = profile

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.profile[item]
```

It is ok to access Investor profile by simply `Investor['name']`,
But it comes to an error when I use `get()` `Investor.get('name')`

Raised: `AttributeError: 'Investor' object has no attribute 'get'`

I know I can fix it by adding a `get()` method to Investor Class, but is it a right way to do? or are there any other special method `__get__` or whatever?

Comment: getters and setters! Yes, as far as I know it is a proper way

Comment: Maybe you should specify why you need a class at all. Nothing in this code suggests that you cannot use a plain `dict` or inherit form `dict` without overriding anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard get has a default as well. So this would be the full version:

```
def get(self, item, default=None):
    return self.profile.get(item, default=default)
```

As for this being proper, as far as I know there isn't any better way so it is by default.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just define a `get` function?

```
def get(self, item):
    return self.profile.get(item)
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, there isn't a special "get" function which already exists and you can inherit from the object class. To get the functionality you want, you need to implement your own "get" function.

If you actually want to create a lot of similar classes to Investor which all have a get() function, then you should create a superclass for Investor to inherit from.

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, profile):        
        self.profile = profile

    def get(self, item):
        if item in self.profile:
            return self.profile[item]

class Investor(Person):
   def __init__(self, profile):
       super().__init__(profile)
```

Comment: Why duplicate the implementation of `dict.get` when you can just *call* `self.profile.get(item)`?

Comment: I'm not. self.profile[item] is calling the __getitem__ function.

Answer (score 0):

How about using @property ?

```
class Investor:
    def __init__(self, profile):
        self._profile = profile

    @property
    def profile(self):
        return self._profile


if __name__ == "__main__":
   inv = Investor(profile="x")
   print(inv.profile)
```

Gives:

```
x
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution that you can have is to use `try:#code except: #code` block in `__getitem__` method.For ex:

```
class Investor:
    def __init__(self, profile):
       self.profile = profile

    def __getitem__(self, item):
       try:
         return self.profile[item]
       except:
         return 0
```

`

This will help you to get dictionary get() method like features without having to add new get() method.

Comment: I don't think there's any good reason to break the expected behavior of `[]` like this.

Comment: What if `profile` is a list.Then, I think it is the shortest and efficient way of getting dict get() method like functionality.

Comment: If you want `get`-like behavior, define a `get` method, like `dict` does.

Comment: But list has no `get` method, and what if `profile` is a list.

Comment: Why should it be a list? Just because sequences and mappings both use `[]` for indexing doesn't mean the two fill the same use cases. Nothing in the question suggests the OP wants to support lists.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an `investor_object`, like:
`investor_object = Investor({'name': 'Bob', 'age': 21})`

You can do either:
`investor_object.profile['name']`
or
`investor_object.profile.get('name')`

Gives:
`Bob`